# Display a newly created thumbnail without saving first?

Tags: php, image-processing, http-headers, thumbnails

I am testing a thumbnail image creator script which creates a thumbnail that can be displayed in the web browser without saving it first.

Currently I have to use the following code to display the image:

```
include('image.inc.php');

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    create_thumbnail('me.jpg', false, 200, 200);
```

But how can I display the dynamically generated thumbnail image on a standard webpage along side html mark-up?

create_thumbnail function:

```
function create_thumbnail($path, $save, $width, $height){

    // Get the width[0] and height[1] of image in an array
    $info = getimagesize($path);

    // Create a new array that just contains the width and height
    $size = array($info[0], $info[1]);

    // Check what file type the image is
    if($info['mime'] == 'image/png'){

        $src = imagecreatefrompng($path);

    }else if($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg'){

        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);

    }else if($info['mime'] == 'image/gif'){

        $src = imagecreatefromgif($path);

    }else{
        // If it isn't a good file type don't do anything
        return false;
    }

    // Create a thumbnail with the passed dimensions
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);


    $src_aspect = $size[0] / $size[1];

    $thumb_aspect = $width / $height;

    if($src_aspect < $thumb_aspect){

        // Image is tall
        $scale = $width / $size[0];
        $new_size = array($width, $width / $src_aspect);
        $src_pos = array(0, ($size[1] * $scale - $height) / $scale / 2);
    }else if($src_aspect > $thumb_aspect){

        // Image is wide
        $scale = $height / $size[1];
        $new_size = array($height * $src_aspect, $height);
        $src_pos = array(($size[0] * $scale - $width) / $scale /2, 0);

    }else{

        // Image is square
        $new_size = array($width, $height);
        $src_pos = array(0, 0);
    }

    // Stop the new dimensions being less than 1 (this stops it breaking the code). Takes which ever value is higher.
    $new_size[0] = max($new_size[0], 1);
    $new_size[1] = max($new_size[1], 1);


    // Copy the image into the new thumbnail 
    // Newly created thumbnail, image copying from, starting x-coord of thumbnail, starting y-coord of thumbnail(0,0 will fill up entire thumbnail), x-coord of original image, y-coord of original image,  width of new thumbnail, height of new thumbnail, width of original image, height of original image
    imagecopyresampled($thumb, $src, 0, 0, $src_pos[0], $src_pos[1], $new_size[0], $new_size[1], $size[0], $size[1]);

    if($save === false){
        return imagepng($thumb);
    }else{

    // Create the png image and save it to passed location
    return imagepng($thumb, $save);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it to base64 (using [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)) and then display it with:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS==" />
```

Comment: I attempted this: `$image = create_thumbnail('me.jpg', false, 200, 200);
 
 echo "<img src=\"data: image/png;base64,".$image."\ />";` which didn't work. Any suggestion as to why?

Comment: @crm `imagepng` returns a boolean value and (optionally...) outputs a raw image stream. If you want to capture that stream, you have to use output buffering: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php

Comment: @crm you didn't convert it to base64.

Comment: This answer is correct to my initial question although I like the suggestion of passing the variable in the url and using $_GET, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to insert an `img` tag and set its `src` attribute to your php script.

Something like:

```
<img src="thumbnailgenerator.php?image_path=me.jpg">
```

Comment: If I wanted to display multiple thumbnails on the page how would I pass the variables to the thumbnail generator script in this instance?

Comment: @crm I don't know how you are doing it now, but an easy solution would be to use a query string: `thumbnailgenerator.php?image_id=5` and get the variable in your php script: `$_GET['image_id']`.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate suggestion but am trying to get it working with the current script.

Comment: @crm Just change the `id` to the `path` you are using now.

Comment: So I could just pass the variables like so: `<img src="thumbnailgenerator.php?image_path=me.jpg&save=0&twidth=200&theight=200">` and then use `$_GET[]`?